# I get an error when I try to run my flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart

this is the error that I get when I enter run flutter in the command line

```
 + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (run:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Any ideas how can I fix it?

I deleted and reinstalled android still thinking that it was a problem with the version I'm using but it still not working

Comment: It could be that you did not included the Flutter SDK's path in the "Path" variable of your environment variables or listed it in the .zsh/.bash in macOS.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it looks like you are using a Windows system. Make sure you have downloaded flutter and added its bin folder to the `Path` variable.

This can be done as follows:

1. Press the start button and type `env`
2. Open "Edit environment variables for your account"
3. Look for an entry called `Path`. If it does not exist, click "New..." to create it.
4. Click on the `Path` item and the path to your flutter/bin folder `C:\<your_path>\flutter\bin`